# Javascript Alert won't show up

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to "hack" a web app by customizing the login page.

I've succefully been able to change an `<img>`, but I can't seem to use some js.

Whenever I try a simple `alert`, it shows up on the source code but won't show up on the page.

I wonder if there's any way they blocked js or if I'm missing something on why my alert won't show up.

Below : screenshot of the img tag i've successfully changed and the js I failed to execute from the firefox dev tools.

[image]

Please let me know if you're missing some informations.

EDIT : I think I've gave you all the wrong idea :)

I'm not hacking anything. I have the source code of a huge web app.

Now what I'm trying to do is to customize some part of a page. I edited the source code adding an alert (that should show up and that won't).

Here is a part of my code :

```
<img id="Img_site" src="/images/custom/Img_site.png" style="margin-left:-40px;"/>
<script type="text/javascript">alert("test js")</script>
```

Comment: When you press 'f12' and go to the console tab, are there any errors?

Comment: How about wrapping the code into IIFE?

Comment: If you want to inject your own JavaScript into certain pages, use a browser addon such as [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (Firefox) or [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) (Chrome).

Comment: What do think should run that code? The content of the script tags gets executed only when the page loads, if you edit it after it doesn't run again. You can execute JS on a page after it's loaded using the javascript console.

Comment: Edited for clarifying

Comment: It's possible (but unlikely) that the `window.alert()` function could have been redefined by some other code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to "hack" a web app that allows users to enter custom code. There is a good change that the developer of that web app put measures in place so strip any scripting. For example i have an application where users can enter custom markup but i have the below code on the front end to strip any script tags and any code in between them before they get submitted to the server. Then on the server I do the same thing to make sure that no script can be passed to the interface effecting users.

```
        var SCRIPT_REGEX = /<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi;
        while (SCRIPT_REGEX.test(html_code)) {
            html_code = html_code.replace(SCRIPT_REGEX, "");
        }
```

Comment: Interesting ... but on the other hand some of these pages use some js so it should be possible right ?

Comment: Some of the pages use javascript or some of the user defined input allows use of javascript that is working? Because my apps that i run the above code on are all utilizing javascript frameworks so the core pages heavily rely on javascript however i just strip the script tags and leave the markup in place for any user defined input.

Comment: Some pages explicitly use the <script> tag

Comment: @SeanWessell Be careful, there are ways of injecting script into HTML without using the `<script>` tag. `on*="..."` attributes for capturing events, for instance.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I know there are ways around this. I was just using it as an example that developers put effort into avoiding script injection which may of may not be the issue for the OP. But thank you for pointing it out for future SO readers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to notice that the content is already loaded when you append the script. So it won't excute. If  you want inyect javascript code to the web you must use the developer tool.